# Указание параметров при объявлении свойства в lsfusion

Tags: lsfusion

В чем принципиальное отличие разных стилей объявлений свойств ассоциированных с классом? Например из документации

```
CLASS Team;
wins(team) = DATA INTEGER(Team);
ties(team) = DATA INTEGER(Team);
```

и из реального кода модуля

```
CLASS Region;
name  = DATA STRING[100] (Region);
regCode  = DATA STRING[3] (Region);
```

почему wins(team) в первом случае и почему name без параметра во втором?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Короткий ответ**

В данном случае, при задании свойств с помощью оператора `DATA`, список параметров в скобках после имени не играет никакой роли, так как оператор `DATA` никак эти параметры не использует, а классы параметров определяются в самом операторе. Задаваться список параметров может для большей читабельности или единообразности кода. Например, вот такое объявление свойства:

```
routeTime(source, destination) = DATA DOUBLE (Location, Location);
```

может иногда дать больше информации, чем

```
routeTime = DATA DOUBLE (Location, Location);
```

**Расширенный ответ**

Давайте немного разберемся со списком параметров в [инструкции =](https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/=_statement/)

1. Среди операторов-свойств есть набор [контекстно-независимых операторов](https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/Property_operators/#contextindependent): это в том числе `DATA`, `FORMULA`, некоторые формы оператора `GROUP`, и т. д. Эти операторы никак не используют список параметров и сами в обязательном порядке определяют классы параметров (сигнатуру) свойства. При объявлении свойств с помощью этих операторов часто список параметров можно опускать, потому что он не несет в себе никакой дополнительной информации.
2. Список параметров может полностью отсутствовать также и при объявлении свойств с помощью [контекстно-зависимых операторов](https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/Property_operators/). Тогда количество параметров, их имена и классы будут полностью определяются правой частью инструкции =, которая задается [выражением](https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/Expression/). Например:

   ```
    currentBalance = receivedQuantity(Item i, Stock s) (-) shippedQuantity(i, s);
   ```

   Параметры свойства в данном случае будут вычислены из правой части инструкции, причем в том порядке, в котором они встречаются в выражении. Таким образом, объявление выше будет эквивалентно

   ```
    currentBalance (Item i, Stock s) = receivedQuantity(i, s) (-) shippedQuantity(i, s);
   ```
3. Если список параметров указан (при использовании справа выражения), то именно он определяет параметры свойства и их классы. Каждый параметр имеет имя, по которому к нему можно обращаться в правой части инструкции =. Явное задание списка параметров является рекомендуемым, потому что позволяет обнаружить на раннем этапе опечатки или ошибки при объявлении свойства.
4. Указание класса параметра является необязательным (класс может быть указан только при первом появлении параметра), но рекомендованным. Также важно понимать, что классы параметров свойства используются в дальнейшем при [поиске](https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/Search_/) свойств, то есть выборе наиболее подходящего свойства, а также при формировании [канонического имени](https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/Naming/#canonicalname) свойства, но указание класса параметра не добавляет неявно проверку на [принадлежность](https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/Classification_IS_AS/) этому классу при вычислении, поэтому такие проверки нужно добавлять явно при необходимости.